# How to show / hide when user changes options

Tags: symfony4

I have a Symfony 4 form `ChoiceType` and an other form.
If the user selects a specific option in the `ChoiceType`, I want to **hide / show the other form before submit**.

I have already tried ...

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
```

... but the event occurs when the form is submitted. Here, I want to show / hide before submit.

In App\Form\SubjectSearch;

```php
$builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
  'choices'  => [
  'show' => true,
  'hide' => false,
  'empty' => false,
],
'label' => 'combobox'
])

->add('context', EntityType::class, [
  'class' => Context::class,
]);
```

In index.html.twig :

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Expected : the second form 'context' must be hidden when user select an option in ChoiceType, before submit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bad annotation between context and subject entities.
I changed **inversedBy** and **mappedBy** in the many to many relation :

```php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Context", inversedBy="subjects")
*/
private $contexts;
```

To

```php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Context", mappedBy="subjects")
*/
private $contexts;
```